# Getting record count in sql alchemy with slow query

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I am working on a mature system that uses sql alchemy not flask sql alchemy. It has one particularly slow search. The requirement is to add pagination. The problem is that if I submit a count search then by my measurements I am seeing a jump of between 50% and 100% on the overall search time . The relevant snippet is below. What I would like is for the total number of records to be returned in the main search and not have to do the secondary count search. ( using _get_count as it is roughly 50% faster than using .count() alone) Any ideas ?

```
query = session.query(BusinessAttributes.name, 
    BusinessAttributes.trading_as,Business.business_ref)\
    .join(Business)\
    .filter(and_(or_(*filters)))\
    .distinct().order_by(BusinessAttributes.name)           

results = query.limit(limit).offset((page-1)*limit).all()   

if page == 1 and len(results) < limit:
    total_business_count = len(results)
else:
    total_business_count = _get_count(query)    

return results, total_business_count


def _get_count(q):
    count_q = q.statement.with_only_columns([func.count()]).order_by(None)
    return q.session.execute(count_q).scalar()
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you have admin access to the backend? You could create (depending on the DB you're accessing) a [materialized view](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Materialized_view) to cache the query and then refresh it on a periodic basis.

Comment: NIce idea , but the query is dynamic based on ui data entry, so I dont think this is an option.